# Simplifying formula for a real-valued root of the quartic

Tags: equation-solving, algebraic-manipulation

I have a minimization [problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/273248/faster-minimization-of-i-x-a-b-x-b-a-x2-a-b-a-2-f) which reduces a 4th degree polynomial with a real valued root. It's easy to get explicit formula for this root, but formula involves imaginary parts which always cancel out when I plug in specific values.

Is there a standard approach to "refactor" this formula to restrict to real-valued computation? Ultimately I'll need a formula to use in Python which doesn't have good complex number support.

$$-\frac{\left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{-54 c(3)^3+216 c(2) c(4) c(3)-432 c(1) c(4)^2+\sqrt{4 \left(24 c(2) c(4)-9 c(3)^2\right)^3+\left(-54 c(3)^3+216 c(2) c(4) c(3)-432 c(1) c(4)^2\right)^2}}}{24 \sqrt[3]{2} c(4)}-\frac{c(3)}{4 c(4)}+\frac{\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \left(24 c(2) c(4)-9 c(3)^2\right)}{12\ 2^{2/3} c(4) \sqrt[3]{-54 c(3)^3+216 c(2) c(4) c(3)-432 c(1) c(4)^2+\sqrt{4 \left(24 c(2) c(4)-9 c(3)^2\right)^3+\left(-54 c(3)^3+216 c(2) c(4) c(3)-432 c(1) c(4)^2\right)^2}}}$$

```
f[x_] = c[0] + c[1] x + c[2] x^2 + c[3] x^3 + c[4] x^4;
root = x /. Solve[f'[x] == 0, x][[2]] (* large formula involving i *)

(* substitute numeric values *)
makePosdef[mat_] := mat . mat\[Transpose];
d = 40;
a = makePosdef@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {d, d}];
b = makePosdef@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {d, d}];
ii = IdentityMatrix[d];
ab = a . b;
ba = b . a;
aba = ab . a;
Clear[c]

(* The result is always real valued *)
root /. Thread[
 {c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4]}  -> {d, -4 Tr[ab], 
    2 Tr[aba + ab . ab + ab . ba], -4 Tr[ab . aba], 
    Tr[aba . 
      aba]}]
```

Comment: It would be somewhat a hack, but in this particular case you could in place of `root` use `ReplaceAll[Simplify @ Re @ ComplexExpand @ root, {i_Im -> 0, Re[r_] :> r}]`, which is not a pleasant-looking thing, but at least does not contain imaginary values.

Comment: Thanks, that may be the best that can be done here, I now realize I'm not guaranteed single real-valued root, it just happens to have a very high probability

Comment: Right, and also those simplifications in `ReplaceAll` are certainly a hack. Also, `ComplexExpand` assumes that all `c[i]` are real. Also, all `Arg` entries are of course in reality either 0 for non-negative arguments, or `Pi` for negative.

Comment: For polynomials of degree there is Cardano's formula. In there is a term which is called _discriminant_; its sign tells you the number of real roots. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Discriminant_and_nature_of_the_roots

Comment: You could use Newton's method and iterate `x|->x-f'[x]/f''[x]` which here gives `g[x_]:=(-c[1]+3*x^2*c[3]+8*x^3*c[4])/(2*(c[2]+3*x*c[3]+6*x^2*c[4]))`. Using initial guess `0` and iterating two times `g[g[0]]` or three times `g[g[g[0]]]` may already give sufficient precision. Btw, in Mathematica there is `Cubics->False` as in `root=x/. Solve[f'[x]==0,x,Cubics->False][[1]]`, found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180740/how-to-exclude-complex-solutions-to-differential-equation).